# How to create a table with 2 panels, each one separate page?

Tags: tables

I wish to create a table with 2 independent panels. Both panels are big enough, so I have to put them on two different pages.What should I do?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[bp]
\caption{\label{tab:summary}\textbf{Summary Statistics}
{\small
Some sentences. }}
\subcaption*{Panel A: Summary Statistics of 21 Commodity Futures}
{\small
\begin{tabular}{p{1.1in}rp{1in}lp{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}}
\hline\hline\\[-5pt]
Commodities & Start Date & Price Unit & Exchange & Spot Price \newline Mean     & Spot Price \newline STD & Con. Yield \newline Mean & Con. Yield \newline STD & Number\newline of Obs. \\
\hline\\[-5pt]
Chicago Wheat & 02/01/1990 & cents/bushel & CME & 446.8  & 179.2  & -18.8  & 60.6  & 1,238  \\
Kansas Wheat & 02/01/1990 & cents/bushel & KCBT  & 471.7  & 188.9  & -2.3  & 65.2  & 1,308  \\
Corn  & 02/01/1990 & cents/bushel & CME & 331.6  & 152.7  & -5.6  & 45.8  & 1,318  \\
Oats  & 27/11/1990 & cents/bushel & CME & 205.1  & 93.2  & -2.8  & 38.5  & 1,277  \\
Soybeans & 02/01/1990 & cents/bushel & CME& 806.7  & 323.2  & 39.6  & 75.2  & 1,294  \\
Soybean Oil & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & CME & 29.4  & 11.9  & 0.0   & 1.9   & 1,316  \\
Soybean Meal & 02/01/1990 & dollars/metric ton & CME & 248.4  & 97.9  & 20.8  & 32.2  & 1,209  \\
Crude Oil & 02/01/1990 & dollars/barrel & NYMEX & 45.0  & 31.2  & 1.6   & 4.5   & 1,221  \\
Heating Oil & 02/01/1990 & cents /gallon & NYMEX & 134.3  & 94.3  & 1.7   & 13.2  & 1,277  \\
Natural Gas & 27/01/1992 & dollar/MMBtu & NYMEX & 4.2   & 2.5   & -0.1  & 0.9   & 1,109  \\
Cotton & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & ICE   & 68.7  & 23.9  & 1.8   & 13.0  & 1,308  \\
Orange Juice & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & ICE   & 114.6  & 35.2  & -2.3  & 12.1  & 1,255  \\
Cocoa & 02/01/1990 & dollars/ton & ICE   & 1764.1  & 750.6  & -31.1  & 84.0  & 1,317  \\
Sugar & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & ICE   & 12.4  & 5.8   & 0.5   & 1.9   & 1,305  \\
Coffee & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & ICE   & 118.2  & 50.8  & -4.1  & 17.9  & 1,327  \\
Platinum & 02/01/1990 & dollars/troy ounce & NYMEX & 846.0  & 495.8  & 19.5  & 46.9  & 1,308  \\
Palladium & 02/01/1990 & dollars/troy ounce & NYMEX & 359.4  & 241.8  & 6.6   & 21.8  & 1,322  \\
Copper & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & NYMEX & 177.6  & 112.8  & 7.7   & 13.6  & 1,265  \\
Lean Hogs & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & CME & 64.0  & 18.1  & 1.9   & 15.1  & 1,242  \\
LiveCattle & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & CME & 87.9  & 25.4  & 2.0   & 8.7   & 1,255  \\
Feeder Cattle & 30/01/1990 & cents/pound & CME& 104.1  & 37.8  & 4.0   & 11.6  & 1,291  \\

\hline\hline
\end{tabular}}
\newpage
\subcaption*{Panel B: Summary Statistics of 12 Agricultural Commodity Futures (Sample Mean)}
   \begin{tabular}{p{1.1in}p{0.35in}p{0.35in}p{0.6in}p{0.6in}p{0.8in}p{0.8in}p{0.8in}p{0.6in}}
\hline\hline\\[-5pt]
Commodities & Long  & Short  & Long/OI \newline (\%) & Short/OI \newline (\%) & Spot Price\newline RW-STD & Con. Yield\newline RW-STD & Net Long\newline RW-STD & Number\newline of Obs \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Chicago Wheat} & 199.0  & 25.8  & 38.9  & 5.0   & 36.9  & 15.6  & 4.8   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{495} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Kansas Wheat} & 40.4  & 2.5   & 26.4  & 1.5   & 37.3  & 16.0  & 1.7   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{495} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Corn} & 428.0  & 50.8  & 24.7  & 2.9   & 25.8  & 11.4  & 11.0  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{495} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Soybeans} & 165.8  & 21.6  & 23.3  & 2.7   & 50.0  & 23.0  & 4.9   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{491} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Soybean Oil} & 89.3  & 8.4   & 25.4  & 2.3   & 1.7   & 0.3   & 3.0   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{493} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Cotton} & 76.4  & 5.5   & 29.4  & 2.0   & 4.4   & 2.9   & 2.6   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{493} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Cocoa} & 27.8  & 2.7   & 15.2  & 1.4   & 113.6  & 35.1  & 1.5   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{496} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sugar} & 278.5  & 46.8  & 29.5  & 4.8   & 1.1   & 0.6   & 8.0   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{485} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coffee} & 47.1  & 3.6   & 25.1  & 1.8   & 8.0   & 1.8   & 1.5   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{496} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Lean Hogs} & 85.7  & 3.7   & 35.4  & 1.4   & 4.5   & 5.7   & 2.7   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{494} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{LiveCattle} & 112.2  & 3.2   & 32.4  & 0.8   & 3.0   & 3.3   & 2.6   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{498} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Feeder Cattle} & 7.7   & 0.6   & 20.3  & 1.6   & 3.8   &      3.1   & 0.4   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{495} \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}%

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE! I can managed, that your table fit to one page. What is actually your problem?

Comment: It would be too crowded if I fit the two panels on one single page. So I wish to put them on two pages. @Zarko

Comment: I see, than you need to split them into two tables. However, your tables are radher huge and is not easily fit in text width. Now I use 20mm for left/right margins

Answer (score 2):

See, if this provide what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={sf,bf},
            textfont={sf},
            justification=centering,
            ]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[group-four-digits = true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=20mm, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[bp]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \small
\caption{\textbf{Summary Statistics} Some sentences. }
    \label{tab:summary}
\subcaption*{Panel A: Summary Statistics of 21 Commodity Futures}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lXll
         S[table-format=4.1]
         S[table-format=3.1]
    *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]}
         S[table-format=4.0]}
    \toprule
\makecell[b]{Commodities} & \makecell[b]{Start Date} 
    & \makecell[b]{Price Unit} & \makecell[b]{Exchange}
        & {\makecell[b]{Spot\\ Price\\ Mean}}     
            & {\makecell[b]{Spot\\ Price\\ STD}} 
                & {\makecell[b]{Con.\\ Yield\\ Mean}} 
                    & {\makecell[b]{Con.\\ Yield\\ STD}} 
                        & {\makecell[b]{Num.\\ of Obs.}}  \\
    \midrule
Chicago Wheat & 02/01/1990 & cents/bushel & CME & 446.8  & 179.2  & -18.8  & 60.6  & 1238  \\
Kansas Wheat & 02/01/1990 & cents/bushel & KCBT  & 471.7  & 188.9  & -2.3  & 65.2  & 1308  \\
Corn  & 02/01/1990 & cents/bushel & CME & 331.6  & 152.7  & -5.6  & 45.8  & 1318  \\
Oats  & 27/11/1990 & cents/bushel & CME & 205.1  & 93.2  & -2.8  & 38.5  & 1277  \\
Soybeans & 02/01/1990 & cents/bushel & CME& 806.7  & 323.2  & 39.6  & 75.2  & 1294  \\
Soybean Oil & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & CME & 29.4  & 11.9  & 0.0   & 1.9   & 1316  \\
Soybean Meal & 02/01/1990 & dollars/metric ton & CME & 248.4  & 97.9  & 20.8  & 32.2  & 1209  \\
Crude Oil & 02/01/1990 & dollars/barrel & NYMEX & 45.0  & 31.2  & 1.6   & 4.5   & 1221  \\
Heating Oil & 02/01/1990 & cents /gallon & NYMEX & 134.3  & 94.3  & 1.7   & 13.2  & 1277  \\
Natural Gas & 27/01/1992 & dollar/MMBtu & NYMEX & 4.2   & 2.5   & -0.1  & 0.9   & 1109  \\
Cotton & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & ICE   & 68.7  & 23.9  & 1.8   & 13.0  & 1308  \\
Orange Juice & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & ICE   & 114.6  & 35.2  & -2.3  & 12.1  & 1255  \\
Cocoa & 02/01/1990 & dollars/ton & ICE   & 1764.1  & 750.6  & -31.1  & 84.0  & 1317  \\
Sugar & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & ICE   & 12.4  & 5.8   & 0.5   & 1.9   & 1305  \\
Coffee & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & ICE   & 118.2  & 50.8  & -4.1  & 17.9  & 1327  \\
Platinum & 02/01/1990 & dollars/troy ounce & NYMEX & 846.0  & 495.8  & 19.5  & 46.9  & 1308  \\
Palladium & 02/01/1990 & dollars/troy ounce & NYMEX & 359.4  & 241.8  & 6.6   & 21.8  & 1322  \\
Copper & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & NYMEX & 177.6  & 112.8  & 7.7   & 13.6  & 1265  \\
Lean Hogs & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & CME & 64.0  & 18.1  & 1.9   & 15.1  & 1242  \\
LiveCattle & 02/01/1990 & cents/pound & CME & 87.9  & 25.4  & 2.0   & 8.7   & 1255  \\
Feeder Cattle & 30/01/1990 & cents/pound & CME& 104.1  & 37.8  & 4.0   & 11.6  & 1291  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\begin{table}[bp]
\ContinuedFloat
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \small
\caption{\textbf{Summary Statistics}}
\subcaption*{Panel B: Summary Statistics of 12 Agricultural Commodity Futures (Sample Mean)}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X
%         S[table-format=3.1]
    *{8}{S[table-format=3.2]}
%         S[table-format=1.1]
%         S[table-format=3.1]
%    *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]}
%         S[table-format=3.0]
                @{}}
    \toprule
\makecell[b]{Commodities}   & {\makecell[b]{Long}}  & {\makecell[b]{Short}} 
    & {\makecell[b]{Long/\\OI (\%)}} & {\makecell[b]{Short/\\OI (\%)}} 
        & {\makecell[b]{Spot Price\\ RW-STD}} 
            & {\makecell[b]{Con. Yield\\ RW-STD}} 
                & {\makecell[b]{Net Long\\ RW-STD}}
                    & {\makecell[b]{Number\\ of Obs}}      \\
    \midrule
Chicago Wheat & 199.0  & 25.8  & 38.9  & 5.0   & 36.9  & 15.6  & 4.8   & 495 \\
Kansas Wheat & 40.4  & 2.5   & 26.4  & 1.5   & 37.3  & 16.0  & 1.7   & 495 \\
Corn & 428.0  & 50.8  & 24.7  & 2.9   & 25.8  & 11.4  & 11.0  & 495 \\
Soybeans & 165.8  & 21.6  & 23.3  & 2.7   & 50.0  & 23.0  & 4.9   & 491 \\
Soybean Oil & 89.3  & 8.4   & 25.4  & 2.3   & 1.7   & 0.3   & 3.0   & 493 \\
Cotton & 76.4  & 5.5   & 29.4  & 2.0   & 4.4   & 2.9   & 2.6   & 493 \\
Cocoa & 27.8  & 2.7   & 15.2  & 1.4   & 113.6  & 35.1  & 1.5   & 496 \\
Sugar & 278.5  & 46.8  & 29.5  & 4.8   & 1.1   & 0.6   & 8.0   & 485 \\
Coffee & 47.1  & 3.6   & 25.1  & 1.8   & 8.0   & 1.8   & 1.5   & 496 \\
Lean Hogs & 85.7  & 3.7   & 35.4  & 1.4   & 4.5   & 5.7   & 2.7   & 494 \\
LiveCattle & 112.2  & 3.2   & 32.4  & 0.8   & 3.0   & 3.3   & 2.6   & 498 \\
Feeder Cattle & 7.7   & 0.6   & 20.3  & 1.6   & 3.8   &      3.1   & 0.4   & 495 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I heavily reformat your table. First I split it into two table, where for second one I use `\ContinuedFloat` option from `caption` package which suppress incrementing table number (both are "Table 1".

I use `tabularx` for fitting it in text with, for columns with numbers I use `S` column type from `siunitx` package, in column headers I use `thead` from `makecell` package. I also reduce inter column space (from default 6 pt to 4 pt) and omit all your use of `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}`.

Temporary are both tables in one page since there is no other text. When  it will be present, LateX will push second table to new page. With selection float option `[b] you can obtain that both tables are at bottom of pages.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for doing so much! They look good. I have only a few concerns. Can you make variable names such as "commodities" flush left? It would look better. Moreover, it is possible to suppress the caption in the second table? If not, I prefer to make it flush to the left.

Comment: This are minor changes. By reading documentation for `makecell˙you will find, that instead option `[b] ` you need to use `[lb]` (left and bottom align).  Regarding the caption of the second table: you can omit it (not good idea) or don't write any text in it (better solution). In decision, what is more appropriate consider, that can happen that table will be split between odd and eve page, so on the next page you will not see the firs part of table ant its caption).